# What is the best way to record in-kind contributions?

Tags: contributions

I am working with an organisation that would like to record in-kind contributions and pro bono support.  These are gifts that they receive from other organisations in the form of services or support rather than cash.

They would like to record these contributions so that they can report on the value to the organisation - e.g. 'in the last year we have received £10,000 of in-kind support'.

What is the best way of recording this in CiviCRM?  Should they just create another financial type for this?  Will this cause any problems as it isn't actually money?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a separate financial type for in-kind donations, you can both track those separately and exclude them from the contribution reports (so as not to confuse things when you try to report on actual monetary gifts).  So far none of the clients I have that track their in-kind gifts in this fashion have encountered difficulties with it.

Hope this helps,
Lesley